# HTML compilation gets blocked by forbidden 'null' data type, even though null can't be a value

Tags: html, angular, typescript, typeerror, ngxs

I've got a problem with my HTML code, where the compiler dies on:

```
Type 'CustomItem[] | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'CustomItem[] 
| undefined'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'CustomItem[] | undefined'.
```

The HTML code looks like this, I even check for the Observable NOT being a null in *ngIf.

```
<library-select
  *ngIf="(data$ | async) !== null"

  [data]="(data$ | async)"
  (itemSelected)="itemSelected($event)"

></library-select>
```

In the corresponding .ts file, the code for instantiating this Observable looks like this:

```
@Select(SelectState.getData) data$: Observable<CustomItem[] | undefined>;
```

Again, no possibility of a null slipping in. Now in the store, the item array is initially undefined, then gets initiated by an http request response like this:

```
@Action(HttpSuccess)
private httpSuccess(ctx: StateContext<SelectStateModel>, action: HttpSuccess) {

const items: CustomItem[] = [];

action.result?.portfolios?.forEach((value, index) => {

  items.push({
    value: value?.username,
    top: {
      topMainText: value?.username,
    },
    bottom: {
      bottomMainText: value?.userType
    },
    id: value?.userId.toString()
  });
```

And again, I can't see why the compiler or typescript would infer a null data type.

I am on Angular 14.2 and I'm using NGXS State Management.

I tried logging out the datatypes of every relevant variable for the entire duration of the HTTP request, store initialization and even when I read the observable in the component .ts file, and it's always either undefined or CustomItem[], not once was it null. I check for null data types with the *ngIf directive right on the  tag, expecting it to not display anything if it really *can *be a null (which it seems like it can't), but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

false, null, undefined. All different values but can loosely be used the same. Key word: loosely.

Your template specifies looking for null: `*ngIf="(data$ | async) !== null"`

But your observable doesn't say it'll hand out null: `@Select(SelectState.getData) data$: Observable<CustomItem[] | undefined>;`

You observable can only give `CustomItem[]` OR `undefined`. There's no way, therefore, it's reasonable to check for a `null` value, as you're doing.

Switch it to checking for undefined and it should be fine: `*ngIf="(data$ | async) !== undefined"`

OR, loosen the equivalence check: `*ngIf="(data$ | async) != null"`

false, null, and undefined are all `==`, but NOT `===`, so `!=` should work, but `!==` certainly won't because they're all different values.

Edit: Another option is the omission of the value at all; `*ngIf="(data$ | async)"` is a shorthand and is true so long as there's a value. That might get round the compiler's issues.

On a personal note; it's one of the reasons I don't like to use the async pipes and having all this kind of thing done in the templates. I'm not sure how it handles those usages...
In theory, it won't display that element at all unless there's a value, but that's fine, it'll keep the ngIf's usage for checking that. Does it also keep the `[data]`'s usage as well? I assume so, as they're both on the element.

I assume it would be different if you split up the usage so that you had a checking element outside, e.g.

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(data$ | async)">
    <library-select
        [data]="(data$ | async)"
    </library-select>
</ng-container>
```

In this case, the `library-select` element doesn't exist at all, and thus no `data$` subscription until there is some data down the line. If you're using a behaviour subject I guess it shouldn't be a problem, but an observable would be?

A behaviour subject will provide, to new subscribers, the last value it broadcast (followed by subsequent ones), as opposed to a plain observable that only ever provides values when it's told to - regardless of who subscribes when.

In that case, once the `library-select` element is then displayed (because `data$` has provided a value) and is rendered and initialised and subscribes, it would be given that last value that allowed it to ngIf into existence and thus work properly.

Again, I hate doing all this stuff in async pipes in the templates precisely because I don't know how it all *exactly* works under the hood, so I stick to standard behaviour subjects/observables depending on the situation and just sub/unsub as part of the component itself, reducing the templates to simple property accessing:

```js
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    private subs: Subscription[];

    constructor(private readonly someService: SomeService) {
        this.subs = [];
    }

    public data: Something | undefined;

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.subs.push(this.someService.data$
            .subscribe((x: Something) => this.onDataReceived(x));
    }

    public ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.subs.forEach((x: subscription) => x.unsubscribe());
    }

    private onDataReceived(data: Something): void {
        if (!data) {
            // ...
            return;
        }

        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

```html
<library-select
    *ngIf="data"
    [data]="data"
    (itemSelected)="itemSelected($event)">
</library-select>
```

And it's still all async, without the hassle of figuring out how it all works depending on what elements you put it on.

Comment: The *ngIf check is there precisely because it threw the error in the first place. I can't apply *ngIf="(data$ | async) !== undefined since this would mean I don't show the select when the data is undefined, which is a real posibility, but I want it to show anyway. I tried the second solution and it unfortunately doesn't work either. :/